# Using Advanced Python Calculator in QGIS Modeler

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to create a column with integer values based on a small function that basically uses conditional statements. In short, a reclassification. My attempt below:

```
def getValue(Etat):
    if Etat == 'Bon':
        value = 1
    elif Etat == 'Moyen':
        value = 2
    elif Etat == 'Mauvais':
        value = 3
    elif Etat == 'Ruine':
        value = 4

value = getValue(<Etat>)
```

While I do not get any errors, the problem is that the new field is not being updated with new values. My thoughts are that it can't find the original field: "Etat", the source.

How should I go about it? Also, what I don't understand how is going to make the updates to the field, surely something is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, due to my lack of not paying enough attention I managed to solved the problem.

I wasn't returning the value, only making assignments.

Comment: Could you help me? I'm trying to use the same toolbox to write the layer name in a new attribute column. I insert in the Formula field the same expression used in field calculator: "value = @layer_name". Unfortunately, python does not recognize the variable @layer_name.

Comment: @christian.gobel Hi. I could try but I'm entirely sure I understood everything. If I'm not mistaken @ character shouldn't be used as part of variable name unless that is some sort of new feature for qgis/arcgis which I am not familiar with. Could you share a little bit more of what you are trying to do?

Comment: sure. I posted my question [here] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316642/advanced-python-field-calculator-qgis-processing-toolbox). I Understand the @ are variables function from QGIS environment. That's why not work in python expression.