# Advanced Python Field Calculator - QGIS Processing Toolbox

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, field-calculator

I'm trying a very simple task. I want to write the layer name in a new attribute column. I managed to do this using `Field Calculator`. But I need to do the same for a lot of files in batch mode, only available in `Advanced Python Field Calculator`. In `Advanced Python...` algorithm I inserted in the `Formula` field the same expression I used in `Field Calculator`: `value = @layer_name`. Unfortunately, python (from `Advanced Python...` algorithm does not recognize the variable `@layer_name`.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why not to use **"Field Calculator" ** in processing also? Is also available. Second though, you can use **"Refactore Fields" ** algorithm to use some formulas.

Comment: Is this inside a model?

Comment: @GSienko I edited the original question. Because I want to do this in batch mode only available in"Advanced Python Field Calculator". I don't know what is and what you mean by "Refactore Fields".

Comment: @ndawson, no this is not inside any model. The algorithm is available in 'Processing Toolbox'.

Comment: In that case, why not hard code the layer name in your expression?

Comment: @ndawson could you explain to me how, please?

Answer (score 1):

Use Field Calculator (not Advanced Field Calculator) from 'Processing Toolbox' in batch mode and as the field value write: decode_uri(@layer, 'layerName'). Works, i've checked it.